# How can I make this work? (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to make this code work like a set of options. I've tested it and regardless of what I put in for the moduleChoice, it takes me straight to gradeTestMain. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main (void) 
{
    int moduleChoice=5;

    printf ("Please choose which module you would like to use.\n");
    printf ("press 1 for GradeTest version 1.1\n");
    printf ("press 0 to exit\n");
    scanf_s ("%d", &moduleChoice);

    if (moduleChoice == 1, 
        gradeTestMain());
    if (moduleChoice == 0, 
        printf ("Thank you for using GradeTest version 1.1! Have a great day!"));
    if (moduleChoice /= 1,0, 
        printf ("That is not a valid choice. Please try again."));
```

Comment: Remember to test that `scanf_s()` was successful!  But there are bigger problems than that in the code, as diagnosed by the answers I see.

Comment: Those are some creative if statements you have there! They happen not to be syntactically illegal, but they sure aren't semantically correct. You really think that `moduleChoice /= 1,0` means moduleChoice is not 1 and not 0? I suggest that you read a C programming book or tutorial and not just guess at the syntax or make it up as you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (moduleChoice == 1, 
    gradeTestMain());
```

should be changed to

```
if (moduleChoice == 1) 
    gradeTestMain();
```

Likewise for other `if`s.

You need to close brackets - otherwise it means

```
if (moduleChoice == 1, gradeTestMain());
```

which means

```
if (moduleChoice == 1, gradeTestMain())
{
    ;
}
```

which means.

evaluate `moduleChoice == 1`, throw away the result, then evalutate `gradeTestMain()`.
Then check whether the return value of `gradeTestMain()` is true or false. But again, because there is nothing inside the `if`, irrespective of whether `gradeTestMain` returns true or false, the result is the same.

Another thing is that

```
if (moduleChoice /= 1,0,
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Change it to an `else`. Change the previous `if` to an `else if`
So you need

```
if (moduleChoice == 1)
    gradeTestMain();
else if (moduleChoice == 0) 
    printf ("Thank you for using GradeTest version 1.1! Have a great day!");
else 
    printf ("That is not a valid choice. Please try again.");
```

It may be a good idea to invest in a book.

Comment: Lol. You have two `))` after every `printf` just as the OP has!

Answer (score 2):

```
int main (void) 
{
    int moduleChoice=5;

    printf ("Please choose which module you would like to use.\n");
    printf ("press 1 for GradeTest version 1.1\n");
    printf ("press 0 to exit\n");
    scanf ("%d", &moduleChoice);

    if (moduleChoice == 1) 
        gradeTestMain();
    else if (moduleChoice == 0) 
        printf ("Thank you for using GradeTest version 1.1! Have a great day!");
    else 
        printf ("That is not a valid choice. Please try again.");
```

this work in C